# external ray and period of Julia sets

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems

Assume that a quadratic function $f_{c}(z)=z^{2}+c$ have attractive cycle with period $p$. Is the number of external rays landed at the fixed point of $f_{c}$ exactly $p$? Does the Julia set is locally connected? I have searched the book by Milnor and Gamelin and many papers by Milnor, but none of them give similar statement.